# How do you avoid unnecessary line spacing in images displayed with JS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

I have a question. I've been working on a new JS game, and have just barely even started, and I ran into a hurdle:

```js
var block = new Array(35);
var blockdata = new Array(35);
var count = 0;
var rand = 0;

while (count <= 35) {
  rand = Math.floor((Math.random() * 3) + 1);
  if (rand == 1) {
    block[count] = "images/t.jpg";
  } else {
    block[count] = "images/g.jpg";
  }
  count++;
}

count = 0;

while (count <= 35) {
  blockdata[count] = document.createElement("IMG");
  blockdata[count].setAttribute("src", block[count]);
  blockdata[count].position = "relative";
  document.body.appendChild(blockdata[count]);

  //inneficient code below XD
  if (count == 5) {
    var mybr = document.createElement('br');
    document.body.appendChild(mybr);
  }
  if (count == 11) {
    var mybr = document.createElement('br');
    document.body.appendChild(mybr);
  }
  if (count == 17) {
    var mybr = document.createElement('br');
    document.body.appendChild(mybr);
  }
  if (count == 23) {
    var mybr = document.createElement('br');
    document.body.appendChild(mybr);
  }
  if (count == 29) {
    var mybr = document.createElement('br');
    document.body.appendChild(mybr);
  }

  count++;
}
```

```css
#content {
  line-height: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://gc.kis.scr.kaspersky-labs.com/AA4B3110-75F6-C945-9AFA-B001BE396F4E/main.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>

<div id="content">
```

The game running can be seen [here](http://untitledgame.eu5.org/aditya)

The images (t.jpg, g.jpg) are put in rows. I do not want a tiny space between the rows, which you could see from the URL above.

I tried using CSS to make it work, but it won't.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You've used a `<br>` element to break the lines. This by default has a specific height/line-height. Consider wrapping your images in a containing element (like a div or section) and removing the wrapper margins `margin: 0;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a solution, thanks to Kantoci.
I kept all the code the same, but I added some CSS:

```
img {
  margin-bottom: -4px
}
```

The other CSS code was unnecessary, and all the `<div>` tags were not required.

Answer (score 0):

It is actually because of `<br>` tag you are adding.

if you want to break without any space then alternate way is to use
`<ul><li>` tag.

then in each `li` you can mention how many blocks needed.

following way can be done:
update style block like this-

```
<style>
body,
ul,
ul li {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}

#content {
    line-height: 10px;
}
</style>

<body>
<ul id="content">
</ul>
<script>
var block = new Array(35);
var blockdata = new Array(35);

var count = 0;
var rand = 0;

while (count <= 35) {
    rand = Math.floor((Math.random() * 3) + 1);
    block[count] = rand == 1 ? "images/t.jpg" : "images/g.jpg";
    count++;
}

count = 0;
var gap = 1;
var list = "<li>";
while (count <= 35) {
    var isLimit = (count > 0 && (5 * gap) + (gap - 1) == count)
    list += isLimit ? "<img src=" + block[count] + "></li><li>" : "<img src=" + block[count] + ">";
    gap = isLimit ? gap + 1 : gap;

    count++;

}
var content = document.getElementById("content");
content.innerHTML = list;
</script>
```

Comment: How am I supposed to implement that in my code? Newbie here :D

Comment: i edited your code, if you use this- margin-bottom: -4px it can be done, but it will just a hack. not proper way of doing in negative margin.

Answer (score 0):

Image element is by default inline-block (`display: inline-block`). This adds this margin at the bottom. You could add `margin-bottom: -4px` to img, or you can make it display: block, but that would break your layout and you will need to use `float: left` on image or use some other css like `display: flex` on images parent.

And ofc, remove `<br>`